# Why is the carousel not showing in the console simulator?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to figure out how I can embed Google Actions responses, such as the [carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel_selector), in a webhook response for DialogFlow.

I am using V2 of the REST protocol, so I am filling `ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE` in the `source` field and the `payload` field contains the Google Actions field as specified (as per [How can I integrate the Google Actions responses in a webhook response in Dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067142/how-can-i-integrate-the-google-actions-responses-in-a-webhook-response-in-dialog)). I am sending the following response:

```
{
   "fulfillmentText":"This is a carousel.",
   "source":"ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
   "payload":{
      "conversationToken":"",
      "expectUserResponse":true,
      "expectedInputs":[
         {
            "inputPrompt":{
               "initialPrompts":[
                  {
                     "textToSpeech":"This is a carousel."
                  }
               ],
               "noInputPrompts":[
               ]
            },
            "possibleIntents":[
               {
                  "intent":"actions.intent.OPTION",
                  "inputValueData":{,
                     "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec"
                     "carouselSelect":{
                        "items":[
                           {
                              "optionInfo":{
                                 "key":"key1",
                                 "synonyms":[
                                    "Option 1"
                                 ]
                              },
                              "title":"Option 1",
                              "description":"Option 2"
                           },
                           {
                              "optionInfo":{
                                 "key":"key2",
                                 "synonyms":[
                                    "Option 2"
                                 ]
                              },
                              "title":"Option 2",
                              "description":"Option 2"
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When trying this out in the console, no carousel is shown. Only the text `This is a carousel.` is displayed. For your information, I did not include the `image` field, as it is optional according to the specification, but even with images there is no carousel displayed.

It's hard to debug this, as my `actions.intent.OPTION` intent is not displayed in `possibleIntents[]` array in the response tab. I expected this `actions.intent.OPTION` intent to be merged with the other intents (such `assistant.intent.action.TEXT`) as generated by the Dialogflow response.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I maybe shooting myself in the foot by using V2 instead of V1 of the Dialogflow REST protocol?

**update after initial feedback by Prisoner**

I tried with the following response, but still not getting any carousel:

```
{
   "fulfillmentText":"Here you go.",
   "source":"ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
   "payload":{
      "expectUserResponse":true,
      "richResponse":{
         "items":[
            {
               "simpleResponse":{
                  "textToSpeech":"Here are your results."
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "systemIntent":{
         "intent":"actions.intent.OPTION",
         "data":{
            "carouselSelect":{
               "items":[
                  {
                     "optionInfo":{
                        "key":"Option1",
                        "synonyms":[
                           "Option2"
                        ]
                     },
                     "title":"Option3",
                     "description":"Option4"
                  },
                  {
                     "optionInfo":{
                        "key":"Option5",
                        "synonyms":[
                           "Option6"
                        ]
                     },
                     "title":"Option7",
                     "description":"Option8"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I also tried to manually create an intent in Dialogflow with returns a 'hardcoded' carousel (that is, without fulfillment callback) and this carousel is shown perfectly. So I am sure that the console is correctly configured.

I am also comparing my response with the ones in [Google Assistant flow with multiple actions_intent_OPTION handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819519/google-assistant-flow-with-multiple-actions-intent-option-handlers), but without success so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shot yourself in the foot - but you have made something that was already a bit complex even more complex. There are two things to look out for:

1. **CORRECTION**: Make sure the `payload` is the same as what used to be `data`, but other fields have changed format.
2. You need to make sure the simulator is in Phone mode and not Speaker mode.

Details follow.

**Documented Dialogflow Differences**

The [Actions on Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/webhook#response) for the Dialogflow response is a little confusing. Instead of providing the full example, it just says that the response that would be under `expectedInputs.possibleIntents` should, instead, be under `data.google.systemIntent`. For V2, that would be `payload.google.systemIntent`.

The `inputPrompt` object is also restructured somewhat so you should be sending a `richResponse` that contains a `simpleResponse` object.

**UPDATE** I've tested this. This is the *entire* JSON that should be returned. Note the contents of `payload` is exactly what the contents of `data` used to be. The `source` field is ignored and has nothing to do with the payload, apparently.

See also https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json which contain some examples.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "This is a carousel"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "systemIntent": {
                "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
                "data": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
                    "carouselSelect": {
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "optionInfo": {
                                    "key": "key1",
                                    "synonyms": [
                                        "Option 1"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "title": "Option 1",
                                "description": "Option 2"
                            },
                            {
                                "optionInfo": {
                                    "key": "key2",
                                    "synonyms": [
                                        "Option 2"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "title": "Option 2",
                                "description": "Option 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Simulator Surface Setting**

Make sure that your simulator is set for the "Phone" surface rather than the "Speaker" surface. Options won't display on a Speaker.

The setting should look like this: [image: phone setting]

**Not** like this: [image: speaker setting]

Comment: Very useful feedback, thanks again. I will try it out shortly.

Comment: Thanks again! So far, still no luck. I edited my original question with my progress update. It's probably a stupid issue (typo?), but I can't see it now.

Comment: Another update: I tried some of the responses on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819519/google-assistant-flow-with-multiple-actions-intent-option-handlers by copying them and none seem to work. Only the text from `fulfillmentText` is shown/read. It seems that `payload` is always ignored. Is `ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE` as `source` correct (as I assume this will indicate how `payload` is interpreted)?

Comment: It turns out we were wrong about the contents of `payload`. It needs to be exactly the same as what is documented for `data`. See my update above, as well as the link to a github repository with more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the update! This indeed solved the problem, the carousel is now correctly displayed. Thanks, your feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks man. I really wish I would have found this answer 6 hours ago. (not even joking) 