# Is it possible to keep selecting an item from a carousel/list?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am displaying a carousel as discussed in [Why is the carousel not showing in the console simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125469/why-is-the-carousel-not-showing-in-the-console-simulator). I am now noticing that the end-user can only select once an item from the carousel. When the end-user select another item subsequently, the default fallback intent is triggered.

Is it possible to select multiple items from a carousel?

In my case, the backend service shows the carousel with an output context (named `my-carousel`) set. The corresponding intent for the `actions_intent_OPTION` event requires that same context `my-carousel` as input context (which works as expected for the first selection). When setting the output context `my-carousel`, I tried several lifespan count values, but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to currently do that the way you tried.

However, you can have another intent trained for keys of carousel (Or use fallback intent) and then process the information this way instead of using `actions_intent_OPTION`.

But this solution would work only for static data/data matching your database.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider your strategy, for sure.